# Один блок наезжает на другой при изменение размера

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Подскажите как исправить наезжание одного блока на другой.
Есть раздел на сайте "Товары", если кликать на табы, то количество товаров меняется и нижний блок наезжает. Как это можно поправить?

Стилей , отступов вроде бы нет никаких. Как это можно поправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели пример кода, который воспроизводит вашу ошибку, так как не понятно как у вас там все устроено.

Comment: <div class="special-btm"> и  <div class="special-top"> конкретно с этими двумя блоками проблема. Второй наезжает на первый. Как устроено я бы сам рад был узнать.Поэтому код не приведу, который воспроизводит. Нужно понажимать на кнопки на сайте чтобы увидеть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не с `padding / margin`, а с `flow:left` у элементов `#portfoliolist .portfolio`
Добавьте в ваш `div#portfoliolist` класс `clearfix`